# Meaningful: translation by significatif

Tags: traduction, anglais

I am puzzled about the interpretation of meaningful in the following phrase

> Intermediate scales: **meaningful** local averages of physical quantities.
>
> Échelles intermédiaires: moyennes locales **significatives** des quantités physiques.

In this context, can we translate *meaningful* by *significatif* ? If not, how can I render its meaning?

Comment: Yes you can it totally make sense !

Comment: Oui absolument quoique, dans ce cas précis, j'aurais probablement préféré **représentatives** tant, sur le plan statistique, une moyenne n'a jamais vraiment **signifié** autre chose... qu'une moyenne. ;) Maintenant cette moyenne peut justement, selon les cas, *être représentative* d'un échantillon ou non... *représenter* quelque chose... ou rien! et c'est bien cela qui importe ici.

Comment: Unless you clarify the purpose of “meaningful” by providing more context, I'm afraid you won't get meaningful answers.

Comment: It seems clear enough to me: whatever local average worth some attention for one reason or another, whether on a microscopic or galactic scale, or in the dense context of human populations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Intermediate scales : **meaningful** local averages of physical of physical quantities.

Nous pouvons imaginer différentes circonstances où ce genre d’affirmation pourrait être utilisé, mais la traduction variera probablement en français selon le contexte. Toutes les utilisations possibles auront cependant en commun que les moyennes locales *« voudront dire quelque chose »*.

Que peut-on vouloir dire par *« vouloir dire quelque chose » ?*

Comme point de départ de la réflexion, je liste des synonymes possibles :

- signifier qqch
- représenter qqch
- indiquer qqch
- *et à la limite,* sous-entendre qqch

L’ennui ici est que tous ces termes ne sont pas exactement synonymes entre eux, et que les adjectifs qui leur sont apparentés ne leur sont pas toujours entièrement fidèles.

**Signifier/significatif**

Ainsi, dire qu’une moyenne locale signifie quelque chose *(qu’elle a un sens)* ne veut pas dire qu’elle soit significative *(elle pourrait être sans intérêt).*

Par contre, si une moyenne locale est significative *(importante ou digne d’intérêt),* elle aura vraisemblablement une signification, quoique celle-ci puisse parfois être inconnue ou simplement supposée.

Par exemple, une moyenne locale anormalement élevée d’un polluant peut être mesurée par un échantillonnage approprié, peut être localement significative dans la mesure où toutes les terres environnantes seraient propres, et ce même si les teneurs mesurées étaient bien moindres que celles mesurées par exemple dans un secteur industriel, mais la source peut demeurer, au moins temporairement, inconnue, la signification réelle et concrète de la contamination peut échapper de prime abord aux analystes.

On pourrait imaginer pour cet exemple une exclamation amusante : *« C’est significatif, oui ! Mais qu’est-ce que ça signifie au juste ? »*

**Représenter/représentatif**

De la même manière, une moyenne locale peut représenter quelque chose sans être représentative.

On peut penser à une analyse chimique d’un échantillon de roche contenant de l’or visible. Le résultat nous représentera qu’il existe de l’or visible dans le secteur *(ce qui en soi peut être intéressant ou significatif)* mais créera potentiellement une moyenne locale très élevée n’ayant que peu à voir avec la réalité *(donc une moyenne très peu représentative)*.

Une moyenne locale pourrait aussi nous présenter très scrupuleusement la réalité *(elle est représentative dans l’acception statistique du terme)* sans pour autant que l’on soit tenté de dire qu’elle représente grand-chose. Par exemple :

- si elle ne se démarque pas de ses environs ;
- ou alors le paramètre testé pourrait l’avoir été dans le but de trouver une corrélation avec un autre qui nous intéressait plus particulièrement, et les variations du premier pourraient s’être avérées trop indépendantes des variations du second pour que l’on s’intéresse à ce que le premier représente.

Dans les deux cas, ce n’est pas que la moyenne ne représente rien, simplement que personne ne songera à mentionner qu’elle représente quelque chose.

**Indiquer/indicatif, sous-entendre/?**

Quant à *indiquer* et *indicatif*, c’est probablement hors du propos de l’original anglais. Et il est difficile de trouver un adjectif construit avec *sous-entendre*.

---

#### Différents contextes

Suite à ce petit tour d’horizon, je propose quelques contextes, pour lesquels les mots retenus pour traduire varieront :

**Contexte académique**

Les moyennes locales qui voudront dire quelque chose seront souvent celles qui pourront servir de modèles de base à un grand nombre d’autres moyennes locales. On traduira dans l’optique proposé en commentaire sous la question par [aCOSwt](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17526), car on veut que la moyenne locale présentée soit aussi représentative que possible des autres moyennes locales de valeurs intermédiaires, un archétype de celles-ci.

Selon l’importance accordée à la représentativité, à la typicité ou au processus d’élection, on pourra utiliser :

- moyennes locales **représentatives**
- moyennes locales **typiques**
- moyennes locales **choisies** *(possiblement* **avec soin**)

**Contexte de recherche pure, contexte de mise en valeur**

Contrastant beaucoup avec celles du contexte précédent, les moyennes locales porteuses de sens seront ici celles qui se démarqueront de leurs environs immédiats et/ou du modèle habituel. On cherchera le contraste, l’anomalie. On pourra les sélectionner en fonction de l’intérêt qu’elles génèrent, de leur importance, de leur signification dans le cadre de l’avancement d’une recherche.

- moyennes locales **significatives**
- moyennes locales **intéressantes** (ou **dignes d’intérêt**)
- moyennes locales **importantes**
- moyennes locales **anomaliques**

**Contexte de populations humaines**

Ici, un paramètre potentiellement très différent de celui de la valeur mesurée prend une grande importance : la présence ou l’absence de populations humaines peut devenir le moteur de l’intérêt généré par les moyennes locales et de l’attention qui leur sera accordée. Ce paramètre compte ici souvent davantage que le simple intérêt statistique de la moyenne *(qui pourrait à la limite être complètement nul).*

L’exemple des températures dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31727) décrit convenablement combien l’intérêt stictement formel aux données statistiques peut n’être que d’un faible poids dans la balance du choix de ce qui est *meaningful*.

L’aspect mathématique pur compte de moins en moins dans le choix effectué, mais les façons d’exprimer la *meaningfulness (si vous me passer l’expression)* pourront néanmoins se rapprocher de celles du contexte précédent :

- moyennes locales **significatives**
- moyennes locales **d’intérêt**
- moyennes locales **importantes**

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que ***significatives*** est ici un peu fort, en ce sens que ça semble limiter la signification aux moyennes alors que d’autres facteurs non-statistiques pourraient entrer en ligne de compte, mais ça pourrait probablement, à défaut de mieux, faire l’affaire. En fait, c’est le meilleur terme qui me vienne à l’esprit.

[aCOSwt](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17526) a proposé en commentaire ***représentatives*** à la place, qui pourrait peut-être aussi faire l’affaire, mais me semble un peu moins satisfaisant.

Je pourrais penser aussi à ***importantes***, mais à nouveau, ce n’est pas aussi satisfaisant, car l’importance pourrait être interprétée comme ciblant primordialement la grandeur numérique, alors que ***meaningfull*** peut s’appliquer à un plus large éventail de paramètres que cette stricte grandeur numérique. De plus, ce terme est encore plus fort que ***significatives***.

J’invente un contexte : supposons la température moyenne mensuelle d’une région montagneuse. Au bas, dans une certaine vallée, des extrêmes aux périodes chaudes et froides, c’est ***significatif*** et ***digne d’intérêt*** d’un point de vue statistique. Dans une autre vallée, une communauté de 5000 habitants, dans un endroit où les extrêmes sont moins marqués : statistiquement, les moyennes ne sont pas forcément ***significatives*** (peu démarquée de l’ensemble), mais sont elles néanmoins aussi ***dignes d’intérêt***, sociologiquement et économiquement. Une autre vallée, occupée en été seulement car l’accès n’y est plus possible assez tôt en automne et jusque tard au printemps : ses températures ne sont ***intéressantes*** qu’en été.

D’un point de vue strictement statistique, ***significatives*** pourrait être utilisé, mais il me semble que ***meaningfull*** inclut ce qui est significatif (statistiquement) et ce qui est digne d’intérêt pour quelqu’autre raison que ce soit, la moyenne locale en soi fût-elle même totalement dénuée d’intérêt.

La question demeure ouverte. Peut-être quelqu’un songera-t-il à un terme encore plus près de l’original.

Comment: Oui! Oui **sauf** que, l'exemple que tu prends correspond à un cas très particulier de grandeur physique. Celui des grandeurs physiques qui ne s'additionnent pas. L'addition de 2 températures n'ayant strictement aucun *sens*, leur moyenne mathématique (qui nécessite pour son calcul l'addition), n'en possède pas plus. Dénuée de sens, une telle moyenne est donc formellement **non significative**. Elle ne *représentera* d'ailleurs pas grand chose d'autre non plus que ce que celui qui l'aura calculée voudra lui faire représenter. Ne reste alors effectivement plus que des questions d'intérêt.

Comment: L'addition de 2 températures ne signifie rien, en effet. Mais lorsque survient la division pour obtenir une moyenne, la valeur redevient significative. Un exemple scientifique: la ligne des arbres (au-delà de laquelle nous avons la toundra) dans l'Arctique suit à peu près la ligne où la température mensuelle moyenne du mois le plus chaud de l'année est de 10°C. Si une température moyenne n'avait aucun sens, on ne ferait certainement pas ce genre d'observations.

Comment: J'aurais pu parler du champs magnétique local, dont les déformations peuvent être utilisée pour l'exploration minière. Leurs variations locales pourraient être grandes sans être intéressante (un peu de magnétite) ou moins grandes et de peu d'intérêt statistiquement, mais intéressantes (beaucoup d'hématite). Les températures sont mieux comprises par les non-professionnels, je crois.